# Select Printer after Previewing the document

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using the PrintPreviewDialog.  Works great, but I really need to allow the user to select a printer instead of just having the print go directly to the default printer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the [PrintDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) class, for example in the next manner:

```
<Button Width="200" Click="InvokePrint">Invoke PrintDialog</Button>

private void InvokePrint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create the print dialog object and set options
    PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
    pDialog.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
    pDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

    // Display the dialog. This returns true if the user presses the Print button.
    Nullable<Boolean> print = pDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (print == true)
    {
        XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument("C:\\FixedDocumentSequence.xps", FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocSeq = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        pDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator, "Test print job");
    }
}
```